# Использование геокодера Яндекс-API из командной строки Windows (wget, curl)

Tags: windows, curl, cmd, yandex-geocoding-api, wget

Всем добрый день, пытаюсь выполнить запрос к геокодеру (интересует геокодирование адреса) с использованием утилит командной строки (wget, curl) для windows.

Запрос из веб-браузера выполняется отлично, дает 1 ответ, результат соответствует ожидаемому (выполняется поиск адреса ...&geocode=РТ+г.Казань+ул.Гудованцева+37)

Запрос из wget выполняется с 0 ответами ввиду того, что wget автоматически кодирует русские буквы в запросе процент-кодировкой, например:

```
---request begin---                                                                                                                                                        
GET /1.x/?apikey=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&format=json&geocode=%D0%D2+%E3.%CA%E0%E7%E0%ED%FC+%F3%EB.%C3%F3%E4%EE%E2%E0%ED%F6%E5%E2%E0+37 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Wget/1.11.4                                                                                                                                                    
Accept: */*                                                                                                                                                                
Host: geocode-maps.yandex.ru                                                                                                                                               
Connection: Keep-Alive                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
---request end---
```

В ответе ожидаемо 0 совпадений:

```
..."request":"%D0%D2+%E3.%CA%E0%E7%E0%ED%FC+%F3%EB.%C3%F3%E4%EE%E2%E0%ED%F6%E5%E2%E0+37"
```

Запрос из CURL по логам уходит правильно, но все же где-то перекодируется, поскольку в результирующем json строка не соответствует вызову.

```
GET /1.x/?apikey=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&format=json&geocode=РТ+г.Казань+ул.Гудованцева+37 HTTP/1.1
Host: geocode-maps.yandex.ru
User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
Accept: */*
```

Из ответа:

```
..."request":"├Р├Т ├г.├К├а├з├а├н├╝ ├│├л.├Г├│├д├о├в├а├н├╢├е├в├а 37"
```

Как сделать так, чтобы можно выполнять запрос из командной строки?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Upd: Проблему удалось решить частично за счет использования транслитерации в латиницу, но все же было бы неплохо оперировать и с исходными данными -- мало ли какие ситуации появятся.